# What to do when a probability problem becomes unwieldy to check via simulation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

I am assuming that some probability problems cannot be solved easily since there may be a lot of cases to handle and it would make miscounting likely.  However, some problems do not simulate well on a computer because of the huge number of possible outcomes.  For example, in a standard $52$ card deck, if we choose $26$ cards, there are almost $500$ trillion card combinations and if we add in $2$ joker cards and choose $27$ instead, the # of card combinations = almost $2$ quadrillion (which is interestingly almost $4$ times as many as $52 \choose 26$).

So my question is if you come across a difficult counting problem, even if you "sweat it out" by hand, how do you check the answer if simulation would take way too much time?  For example, using a $54$ card deck (containing $2$ jokers), how many $27$ card hands contain $1$ or more jokers, at least two $7$ card flushes, at least one $10$ card straight, and exactly one set of quads (such as K,K,K,K)?  You don't have to actually compute the answer as I am just trying to come up with a difficult to simulate counting problem. I didn't spend much time coming up with this example so I don't really know how hard it is to solve but I would think with the huge number of possible outcomes it might be a "bear" to count correctly.

Note that a joker can count as any "missing" card we need to make a "winner".  For example, if all the conditions above are met except there is no quad (K,K,K,K for example) but we have a triple (K,K,K for example), the joker can be used to satisfy that missing K thus making a "winner" combo.

What makes this problem seem very difficult to me is that there could be 2 jokers and either one could satisfy any missing requirement and even count for multiple missing requirements at the same time.  For example, if we only get $1$ joker but have $2$ requirements unmet and it just so happens that joker can fulfill both since we can make the joker any card we want that is not already in the hand. An example would be we are missing a 4th King and that same King also completes the 2nd flush.

Assume the $54$ card deck is well shuffled and each card is equally likely to be drawn from it for any $27$ card draw.

Note that the flushes can be longer than $7$ and the straight can be longer than $10$ as long as those minimum requirements are met.  Also a straight flush of length $10$+ would satisfy both requirements for a flush of length $7$ and a straight of length $10$.

Even if someone came up with an answer to this problem, how would it be checked for accuracy?

Comment: The large number of possible outcomes is not a problem for simulation.  There are only two difficulties: (i) the event we are interested in is quite unlikely or (ii) verification of whether the event has happened is expensive.

Comment: Well with the 2 jokers being able to be "cast" into any card not already in the 27 card hand and with around 2 quadrillion card outcomes, how can a computer simulate that in a reasonable amount of time?  My question is how can someone know if they get the answer to this card problem correct?  What would they check it against?

Comment: If in the very modest case of $10000$ runs of a simulation, our event happens $2000$ times, then we are estimating a proportion. Our estimate is $0.2$, and the usual normal approximation will give us a say $99\%$ confidence interval.

Comment: Could Mathematica handle a probability problem like this or would it sit there for an eternity cranking away at an answer?  Would it give you some indication of the estimated time to solve?  I've never used it I was just curious.

Comment: Is the difficulty of computing unlikely events because a sample run of $10000$ iterations of simulation might yield no winners, therefore an accurate estimate cannot be extrapolated?  I problem I have with a partial simulation is that the "winners" might not be "spread out" uniformly in the simulation so you may get x number of winners in "block a" but a completely different number of winners in block b so how would either block be a good estimate of the total number of winners?  Neither of them may be.

Comment: I do not use Mathematica. A number of specialized languages handle simulations. The jokers business would make for unpleasant programming. One can often make an order of magnitude correct estimate of a probability, or do a trial not very long run. If the number of hits is not close to $0$, we can estimate how long a run will give us the desired accuracy.

Comment: About your previous comment, if the simulation is done carefully, and the event is not too unlikely, different blocks will probably yield roughly equal proportions. If the event is quite unlikely, the simulation will give results that are in a sense roughly right ($0.01$ is close to $0.000001$), but the *relative error* may be large.

Comment: What worries me about a partial simulation is the winners may be "nestled" in a certain "chunk" of the outcomes and unless you program it manually, you may not have control of where the simulation "starts" (for example it may start with all the low numbered cards).  There could be millions of simulated hands before even 1 winner is found but there could be millions of winners as well. I made this problem up myself but I have no idea how many winners there are except I found 1 winner on paper manually just to make sure it was possible. It is interesting to count the min # of cards for a winner.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of advanced methods for dealing with excessive variance in simulation output. In your case, you are going to get a lot of hands that do not satisfy your criteria, hence it will take a lot of simulations to get the correct ratio of successes to failures. Two techniques come to mind to address this...neither of which are "plug and chug" type cookbook procedures...you'll still have to think!

They are [Importance Sampling and Stratified Sampling](http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/MCS_Var_Red2.pdf). Both of these techniques essentially bias the simulation towards the region of the sample space most likely to generate "hits". Then, the results are de-biased to get the estimate. The tricky part is determining how to bias your simulation to achieve a reduction in sampling variance.